# Is there a free Java caching library that provides statistics and preserves state on restart?

Tags: java, caching

*[Edited] I am re-re-writing my question, hoping to be this time following the rules good questions and asking about a "narrowed enough" topic. I keep the information I initially provided, in case any reader is interested in details.*

---

***My question:***

I have been investigating free Java caching libraries and I found that all of them provide more or less the same features. But there are 2 tools that stand out over the rest, because they provide a distinctive feature:

- EHCache: Provides statistics for the cached elements. At any point you can get the metadata of each element, having access to details, such as the hit count - the number of times the entry was requested while it was in the cache.
- Infinispan: Provides a persistence-based mechanism to preserve cached data. This allows applications to not lose the cached elements on restart. Several persistence methods are supported, like database and filesystem.

I am wondering if there is another library that combines these 2 great features. Does anyone know about one?

Thank you.

---

***My original post:***

I am working on a component that *provides access to a reporting layer*. Reports are generated **on demand**, but when a given report has been run the result (a Java object) **can be cached** and served again later if the same report is requested, without going again to the reporting engine.

I need to limit to "**X**" (configurable) the number of cached items. When the cache size has reached "**X**" elements and a new (not cached) report is requested I need to remove the "**least-frequently-used**" entry (LFU).

My component is notified when the reporting data changes in the data warehouse. In that case I need to:

- Figure out which ones are the "**Y**" "**most-frequently-used**" reports (being **Y < X**).
- Invalidate the cache.
- Re-generate those reports through the reporting engine.
- Re-cache them.

These are all operations typically provided by most of the caching tools/libraries.

An additional requirement for me is that the cached reports **must survive JVM restarts**. This is, I cannot lose the information of which ones were the cached entries and I cannot re-generate them every time my application is restarted - because it would be too much load on the reporting engine.

**My problem:** I *cannot find* a **free** library that covers all my needs. In summary, these would be the required features:

- Free / commercial-friendly license.
- Persistent storage, saving state on JVM/server restart/crash.
- Java API, providing element statistics. I need to be able to "select the top X elements in cache" - using the eviction algorithm ranking as ordering.
- Easy to integrate with an application running on Tomcat.

The closest option I found is EHCache. It exposes the hit count for each element - but not the "real" ranking used by the eviction algorithm. Besides, persistent restartable mechanism is available only for a non-free version - BigMemory, from Terracotta.

Other alternative I have seen is Infinispan, but it does not expose entry-level statistics - only cache-level statistics - and requires JMX.

Comment: http://memcached.org/

Comment: What is the driver for having persistent storage of the cache? If the driver is to be able to have the cache available on restart, you could just write a function that runs on startup to repopulate the cache, taking the data from a separate, permanent store.

Comment: @robjohncox This is why: I need to cache reports, which are generated on demand. I need to limit to "X" the number of stored items. When "X" has been reached and a new report is requested I need to remove the "least-frequently-used" entry (LFU). When the reporting data changes in my data warehouse I need to know which ones are the "Y" most-frequently-used reports (Y < X), invalidate the cache, re-generate those reports, and re-cache them. All these are the typical operations of caching tools. I just need to avoid re-generating everything when my server restarts. Does this make more sense?

Comment: May have been better to put on hold as "too broad."  SO is not effective at listing out your requirements and expecting us to come up with a design or architecture.

Comment: I would not say it is "too broad", but I accept the decision if you believe it is. I could summarize my requirements as "I am looking for what most of the free Java caching libraries provide, plus statistics, plus restartability". Actually I found that EHCache provides statistics, and Infinispan provides restartable persistent caching. So I am not looking for something really new, I am just wondering if there is another library (not design or architecture) that provides both. I don't necessarily expect you guys to provide a solution, maybe the right answer to my question is "there is nothing".

Comment: @sanbhat I looked into Memcached wiki and found this: "Many users want K/V stores that are able to persist values beyond a restart, or beyond available physical memory. In many cases memcached is not a great fit here [...]". [Source](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/NewOverview)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you are trying to do is create a document store that has functionality found in some caching frameworks, but itself isn't really a cache. I think you will have more luck finding the right solution by putting the idea of a cache to the side, and instead look at how you can build a persistent document store that has the functionality you require:

- Purging old documents
- Statistics about the documents being stored

As suggested by @djechlin, this is more of a design & architecture question that would be difficult to answer in this forum.

Best of luck.

Comment: Maybe I should have provided more details. I need to store Java objects, not files. The reports are "live" dashboards. My reporting engine returns an object graph containing the reporting data. I can cache that data but I cannot cache (store) the final report because it depends on user settings. Also, several users can "share" the same data, but reports are different for each one. This post-processing is quite fast. Getting the data from the reporting engine isn't fast - it is a bottleneck. This is why I need the cache. Sorry about this back and forth, and thank you very much for your time! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try Jboss' Cache: http://docs.jboss.org/jbossclustering/cluster_guide/5.1/html/jbosscache.chapt.html

it has eviction algorithm, persistent, it's free.

Comment: Using JBoss Cache is discouraged, even by JBoss community: https://docs.jboss.org/author/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=4784597

Comment: BTW, JBoss Cache does not provide element-level statistics, only cache-level statistics.